# Progress_bar with neuralnet

Tags: r

I teach a neural network on a large amount of data ~ 300k lines.
How can I follow the process inside neuralnet? I think something with progress_bar (), but I don’t know how to connect it to neuralnet()

```
NN <- neuralnet(price ~ city  + ... + paint_color, trainNN,
               hidden = c(7,3),  linear.output = F,
progress_bar()????)
```

Comment: Did you look at the `lifesign` and `lifesign.step` arguments?

Comment: @G5W yeah. thnx